# How to reorganize a table in standard sql?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table like

```
Id | Name | Num
---------------- 
#1 | a    | 3
#1 | b    | 4
#2 | a    | 1
#2 | e    | 2
```

and would like to reorganize it into

```
   | a | b | e
---------------
#1 | 3 | 4 |
#2 | 1 |   | 2
```

---

I could actually do it in python with pandas library, but it is extremely slow when the data set is large.
I wonder if it could be done in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called pivoting.  A general purpose method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
      max(case when name = 'a' then num end) as a,
      max(case when name = 'b' then num end) as b,
      max(case when name = 'e' then num end) as e
from t
group by id;
```

This assumes that you want three additional columns and you know the names.  If you want columns for any value in `name`, then you need to construct dynamic SQL.  If you follow the template above, it might not be too hard to construct such a query in Python, by querying the table for the values in the column.